# Difference between web Reference and Service reference in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

The only difference I know from visual studio point of view,for adding WCF service you have to take service reference and for web service you have to take web reference.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

If cou click on the "Advanced..." button in the "Add Service Reference"-Dialog you get a short explanation at the bottom under "Compability":

> Add a Web Reference instead of a
>   Service Reference. This will generate
>   code based on .NET Framewrok 2.0 Web
>   Service technoligy.

Basicaly that means "Web Refrences" are .net 2.0 compatible, but as you already mentioned WCF needs Service reference, but you can also use Service Reference for e.g. basic SOAP-Services, but then you need .net >2 to link/run that assembly.